# Overload Array function based on the type of its elements

Tags: swift

Is it possible to achieve something like this in Swift?

```
extension Array {
    func processItems<Element: Protocol1>() { 
        for item in self {
            // deal with Protocol1 objects
        }
    }

    func processItems<Element: Protocol2>() {
        for item in self {
            // deal with Protocol2 objects
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to extend the `Array` and overload `processItems` based on the type of elements in the array.

An alternative would be to either have a single function and to use optional casting/binding, however I'd loose type safety this way, and might end up with a mammoth function containing a lot if `if-let`'s

```
func processItem() {
    for item in self {
        if let item = item as? Protocol1 {
            // deal with Protocol1 objects
        } else if let item = item as? Protocol2 {
            // deal with Protocol2 objects
        }
    }
},
```

or to declare `processItems` as a free function:

```
func processItems<T: Protocol1>(items: [T]) {
    // ...
}

func processItems<T: Protocol2>(items: [T]) {
    // ...
}
```

However I'd like to know if I can "embed" the function into the `Array` class, to keep it localized. If this is possible, then the technique could be applied to other generic classes (either built-in or custom).

Comment: Your own "solution" will work on mixed arrays, whereas your question seems to stipulate that you do NOT want to support mixed arrays. Mixed, or single non conformant type arrays will give a compile time error using your preferred pattern (or @jtbandes solution, which does work). Is a compile time error what you want?

Comment: @Grimxn that's another reason I'd prefer a statically bound  function. Initially I started with free functions (updated the answer with those), however I wanted to know if I can move the functionality to a more appropriate place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
extension Array where Element: Protocol1 {
    func processItems() {
        for item in self {  // item conforms to Protocol1
            ...
```